# What does the “Permanently Disabled” setting in my BIOS actually do?

Tags: bios, thinkpad

I have two settings in my Lenovo Thinkpad BIOS, called "Computrace" and "Intel AT". I permanently disabled both of them because of privacy concerns and the fact that my computer is not used in any corporate structures. I am just curious, did that actually permanently burn an e-fuse in the CPU, or is that reversible?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is irreversible, see [discussion on Thinkpad forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/BIOS-option-to-quot-permanently-disable-quot-Computrace/td-p/104500). Both Activate and Disable are permanent.

So disabling them is reasonable.

How Computrace/Absolute Persistence exactly keeps itself stealthy and functional is probable something the service provider keeps between them and the BIOS & motherboard manufacturers.

E.g. see [thoughts on computrace](http://bartblaze.blogspot.co.at/2014/11/thoughts-on-absolute-computrace.html), one of the recommendations from their support is to replace the motherboard if the trace client can't be deactivated.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a parameter in the UEFI configuration flash.

Comment: Apparently, it is in some BIOSes